# Bootstrap theme doesnt work properly in react

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I was experimenting with react, so i recreated my html site to react trying out components. So, the site showed up on my PC and it was perfectly right. Everything in order. But then when viewed on a mobile(xs device) the view is that of a Tab(md device). So, all the text is ultra small.

I'm puzzled as to what is that happened. I'm sharing the link to hosted example. http://react.umangmahilatailors.org/

Note: When testing the site on Responsive design mode in firefox, it is responsive and adjusts accordingly. But, on a real device it doesn't.

Comment: Please add some code snippets of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with React, but it should be fixed by adding the following to the `<head>`-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```